# MySQL - Pull most recent value within date range for group of IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the query below

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(hd.value AS SIGNED)) as case_count
FROM historical_data hd
WHERE hd.tag_id IN (45,109,173,237,301,365,429)
AND hd.shift = 1
AND hd.timestamp BETWEEN '2018-04-10' AND '2018-04-11'
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

and with this I'm trying to select a SUM of the value for each of the IDs passed, during the time frame in the BETWEEN statement - but the most recent respective to that timeframe.  So the end result would be a SUM of the case_count values for each ID passed in at the last timestamp the ID has i nthat date range.

I am having trouble figuring out HOW to accomplish this.  My historical_data table is HUGE, however I do have very specific indexing on it that allows the queries to function fairly well - as well as partitioning on the table by YEAR.

Can anyone provide a pointer on how to get the data I need?  I'd rather not loop over the list of IDs and run this query without the SUM and a LIMIT 1, but I guess I can if that's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(hd.value AS SIGNED)) as case_count
FROM historical_data hd
WHERE hd.tag_id IN (45, 109, 173, 237, 301, 365, 429) AND
      hd.shift = 1 AND
      hd.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(hd2.timestamp)
                      FROM historical_data hd
                      WHERE hd2.tag_id = hd.tag_id AND
                            hd2.shift = hd.shift AND
                            hd2.timestamp BETWEEN '2018-04-10' AND '2018-04-11'
                     );
```

The optimal index for this query is on `historical_data(shift, tag_id, timestamp)`.